# how to Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 for flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried following the documentation but I could not make it work I do not know how the Authorization works in the new version I tried downloading a new private key and do not how to use it to send notification to a specific user using that authorization method

this mycode

```
      void sendPushMessage(String token, String body, String title) async {
    await http.post(Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization':
              'private key'
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
          'Priority': 'high',
          'data': <String, dynamic>{
            'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            'status': 'done',
            'title': title,
            "sound": "test.wav",
          },
          'notification': <String, dynamic>{
            'title': title,
            'body': body,
            "sound": "test.wav",
            'android_channel_id': ''
          },
          'to': token
        }));
  }
```

how do upgrade this to this

```
       void sendPushMessage(String token, String body, String title) async {
    await http.post(Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization':
              'how do I get this key'
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
    "message": {
        "token": "token",
        "notification": {
            "body": "This is an FCM notification message!",
            "title": "FCM Message",
            "sound": "sound.mp3"
        }
    }
}));
  }
```

Comment: Firebase Cloud Messaging doesn't (and never has) target users, but rather targets devices. Sending a message to a specific device is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices). If you're having trouble making that work, edit your question to show the [minimal code and steps that allow any of us to reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and any error message you get from that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry I meant to say devices

Comment: Getting the authorization token is quite well documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server). If you can't get that to work, edit your question to show what you tried based on that documentation.

Comment: @muhamadtahsin please did you get this to work?

Comment: no i did not i still use the old version

Comment: If you wan to get the access token follow this youtube video:
https://youtu.be/oNoRw69ro2k?si=I2j86hOkSszSr4Bf

it shows how to generate access token,
you can send notification from postman, just add the access token and it asks you to login to the google something and it should work.

However, I am still not able to send notification from the app using provided access token!